# Change Ganache-Cli account using the MetaMask

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask

I am making a Voting Dapp, learning from the tutorial given
[here](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2)

In Which all the transactions are happening from the single account but as ganache given 10 accounts, I want to change the account and perform the transaction.

Is there any way I can use MetaMask to do it ?

Comment: refer to this guide: http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/truffle-with-metamask#using-metamask-with-ganache

Answer (score 2):

1. Go To Profile Section -> Import Account
2. From Ganache-Cli or Ganache Gui Copy Private KEy Of any One Account and Paste 
   In Private Key Option menu
3. **Hit Enter And Boom** You Are Done (Check You are Running On localhost :8545 if using ganache-cli and if using gui the 127.0.0.1:7545)

Answer (score 1):

Sure,

- Configure your DApp to [work with MetaMask](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check)
- Choose custom RPC in the list of blockchains in MetaMask
- Enter RPC URL of `ganache-cli`. By default `Ganache-cli` is started at `http://localhost:8545`
- Import all unlocked accounts from `Ganache` to `MetaMask`. You can see private keys of those accounts in the console.

That's it. You are connected to `Ganache` through `Metamask`. And you control `Ganache` accounts from MetaMask.